# Pandas split column into two and get name suffix error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, one column is temperature (human) but values are intermixed , celsius and fahrenheit, i want to break this column into two columns (keeping the original one)

```
#C Temp will be added to the end of df 
df = df.join(df.Temp.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x > 43 else x))

#F Temp will be added to the end of df 
df = df.join(df.Temp.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x < 43 else x))
```

I thought `df.Temp.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x < 43 else x)` will return a series that will be joined to the end of `df`, but i am getting this error

```
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'Temp'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is that the implicit `name` attribute of the on-the-fly calculated `Series` inside of your calls to `join` will also be `'Temp'` since it's a derived calculation from that column. Since `'Temp'` already exists in the DataFrame, it's raising an Exception to indicate that it doesn't know what kind of name change (via suffix) you want to use to prevent name overlap.

You can provide an `rsuffix` argument to `join` which will append a given string to the name, for the column coming from the *right* operand of the join (in this case, the one inside the function call). For example:

```
df = df.join(df.Temp.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x > 43 else x),
             rsuffix='_Celsius')
```

to get a column named `"Temp_Celsius"` in the modified output DataFrame. There is also the option of using `lsuffix` to provide a string that will be appended to the *left* operand if you'd prefer for that column name to change instead (or you can provide *both* if you want neither column to retain the original name).

However, note that you are always omitting any `on` arguments (join criteria) in your use of `join` -- meaning you default to "joining" by the index. Really, what you want is to simply write into existence a new column derived from an old column, which gives you the opportunity to declare the name, such as:

```
df['Celsius'] = df.Temp.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x > 43 else x)
```

This is preferable because it much more clearly expresses your intention, which is not to join but to create a column. Further, since the default join method is `'left'`, if you happened to have duplicate indices, you could potentially end up joining multiple times for each duplicate in the left-hand index, and because that index is the same as the right-hand index (and would therefore also have duplicates) it could mean you would silently and erroneously introduce more duplicates with each join.

You may also choose to use `map` instead of `apply` since upon accessing a column, you'll be working with a Series object.

Comment: works great thanks, but why would I use applymap and apply the function on all the df cells, there is different types of data and all other stuff ?

Comment: I expanded a bit in the middle to highlight why simply creating a new column of data makes more sense here than using `join`. On the other part, note that I'm not suggesting to use `applymap` which is a DataFrame method, rather to use plain `map` which is a Series method. `Series.map` is meant specifically for element-wise operations, whereas `apply` has some extra checking for functions that can vectorially operate on the whole `.values` data object in one go.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that you can compute the required series much more efficiently and elegantly using the `where` method:

```
df['Celsius'] = df.Temp.where(df.Temp > 43)
```

This is a vectorized solution which means the inner loop is implemented in C. `.apply` should be avoided as it uses a python loop and can be much slower. Also, `lambda` functions are to be avoided where possible as they will also slow you down over many iterations. Pandas as loads of built-in functionality for these kinds of problems.